# How to re-check checkbox after submiting a form in php?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, checkbox

Here's my problem: 
I got 11 checkbox on my website for a form creating accounts. When I submit the form (which is POST on the same page) I verify that mandatory input are there. In the case one is missing (ex. the password), I want to keep information that has been entered before INCLUDING checkbox. My problem is: How?

Here's my checkbox:

```
<table class="adroite">
      <tr><td>NES<input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="NES"/></td>
      <td>SNES<input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="SNES"/></td>
                <td>N64<input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="N64"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>NGC<input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="NGC"/></td>
                <td>Wii  <input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="Wii"/></td>
                <td>WiiU  <input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="WiiU"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>GB <input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="GB"/></td>
                <td>GBC <input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="GBC"/></td>
                <td>GBA  <input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="GBA"/></td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>DS <input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="DS"/></td>
             <td>3DS <input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="3DS"/></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
```

You see that checkbox are name chkcons[]. I use this method to save the results in MYSQL after the checkup.

So, how can I tell my PHP: See, this checkbox was checked, so keep it check after submit?
Thanks!

Comment: put some logic into your PHP to see what was submitted and add a `selected="selected"` attribute to the checkboxes as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Quick example

`<input type="checkbox" name="chkcons[]" value="NES" <?php if(in_array('NES', $_POST['chkcons'])){ ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>/>`

Answer (score 0):

Why not to validate before submission using some `jQuery` or `JS`?

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599917/validate-form-before-submitting-to-php)

for checkBox validation check [here](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/checkbox-validation/7002/4)

and if you want to do that using `PHP`(not a good move) then [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238965/input-values-lost-when-form-submitted-with-errors) will be helpful.

but I prefer to do this using `JS`

Comment: You should validate server side. Users can disable Javascript. Validating with Javascript is a nice addition though.

Comment: yes, Server side is must, but you should check it on client side as well to save time and resources.
BTW I've attached PHP link as well.
I said that so coz, only server side validation is horrible idea!!!